# How do I reduce the line spacing between my bulleted lists in HTML?

Tags: html, html-lists

I've got a bullet point list that I need to remove the spacing from *(look image below)*.

**IMAGE :**

[image]

**CODE:**

```html
<ul>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Registrations&nbsp;</span>
<ul>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Business name</span></li>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">....</span></li>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Trade marks/designs/patents</span></li>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Vehicle registration</span></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Membership fees</span></li>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Accountant fees</span></li>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">.....</li>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Insurance&nbsp;</span>
<ul>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Building and contents</span></li>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">...</li>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Business assets</span></li>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Business revenue</span></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Printing</span></li>
<li style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Stationery and office supplies</span></li>
```

I understand its the fixed issue with the  being read as a space but I've tried variations of ul style, margins and line heights from other stack overflow questions but I'm having no joy as I'm not entirely sure where to put the code in to the list. Could someone tell me where exactly to insert the necessary code to change it please? Apologies for my very limited coding knowledge here. Exact help would be greatly appreciated though!

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please be sure to upvote / accept answer to close the post and to show others the solution if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a CSS solution. This will do what you need. Add it to your CSS.

```
ul, li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```